# Move "Customize and Add To Cart" Button

Tags: magento2

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently working on customizing the product page for bundle products in Magento 2. Could you please provide guidance on the proper procedure to relocate the "Customize and Add To Cart" button on these bundle product pages?

I appreciate your assistance and expertise in this matter.